# Undefined behavior while printing 0x85 or 0x95

Tags: c

When I try to print `0x15` to `0x75` using `printf("%2x")`, I see the expected output:

> 15
>   75

But if I try to print `0x85` or `0x95` am getting `0xffffff85` and `0xffffff95` as output. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char test = 0x85;
  printf("\n test hex: %2x \n", test);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test hex: ffffff85
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since test is a *signed* char, and 0x85 and 0x95 (actually anything between 0x80 and 0xFF) has the high-order bit set, the result will set signed-extended with 1's when it's promoted from char to int.

Try declaring test as unsigned char.

Answer (score 8):

Try u_char (well `unsigned char`, R is right) test;

char is signed for you and is being converted to an int.  If the high bit 0x80 is set, it is becoming a negative number.

Comment: `unsigned char`. `u_char` is a nonstandard alias present on some systems.

Answer (score 2):

As a small extension to Seth's answer, You are printing an int-wide hexadecimal number. (That's what your format string is saying to do).

If you wanted to print a char sized hex number, you could use:

```
printf("test hex: %2hhx\n", test);
```